# Were there multiple Adi-Shankaras as claimed by some people?

Tags: adi-shankaracharya

I came across [this](https://twitter.com/vsvs999/status/1089713212331683840) surprising tweet just today. It claims that there were multiple Adi-Shankaras. The gentlemen mentions Sringeri records verify this. To my knowledge, this is something new that I have never come across.

So, the question is what are those records and what proof do they offer to the existence of multiple Adi-Shankaras?

Comment: this seems to be a linguistic, logical contradiction.  There can be multiple Adi-Shankaras only if they were twins or triplets or something.

Comment: @S K For once, we seem to be in agreement.

Comment: There were multiple shankaras and not multiple Adi Shankaras. According to that theory, Adi Shankara is one of them.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma I did search for that as well. It turned up a different question which I just posted. But are there any sources that says that the multiple shankaras and Adi-Shankara being one of them theory is recognized by the mathAs?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure for what I am saying but I guess Adi Shankaracharya is only one person but after him there is a post of Shankaracharya for each Math (Adi Shankaracharya had established 4 Mathas in four different direction of India during his life). So it may be possible that the records are of those persons who had received the post of Shankaracharya for Sringeri Matha.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Yes, that would be a one logical path to take, but I am looking for something more factual.